# Give memory to object from another class Java

Tags: java, memory-management, pass-by-reference

I am a newbie to Java (I come from the C/C++ background) and I was having a hard time figuring out how to allocated memory of a data member in one class from another. For eg,

```
Class A 
{
    B bInA;
    C cInA;

    public void foo(someValue)
    {
         cInA = new C();
         cInA.foo(bInA, someValue)
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         A myA = new A();
         myA.foo(xyz)

         // myA.bInA.value should be equal to xyz
    }
}

Class B { ... }

Class C 
{
    public void foo(bInA, someValue)
    {
          bInA = new B();
          bInA.value = someValue;
    }
}
```

Can I do something like this in java?
Any help will be much appreciated.

----EDIT-----

```
Class A 
{
    B bInA;
    C cInA;

    public void foo(someValue)
    {
         cInA = new C();
         bInA = new B();
         cInA.foo(bInA, someValue)
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         A myA = new A();
         myA.foo(xyz)

         // myA.bInA.value should be equal to xyz
    }
}

Class B { ... }

Class C 
{
    public void foo(bInA, someValue)
    {
          bInA.value = someValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: okay so in the constructor of A i can initialize C, something like cInA = new C()?

Comment: Yes.  That aspect is the same as C++.  That's also about where the similarities end.

Comment: Even after giving a 'new' I am getting NPE, bInA is null

Comment: You have to assign the new instance to bInA inside of A.  Where you did it, it just assigned it to the input parameter that just happened to have the same name.

Comment: So now i tried to assign the new instance in A and then passed the new instance and value to C and had bAsParamInC = someValue, still the bInA does not reflect the changes.

Comment: Please post your most recent code.  You're talking about a new variable that's in your current code.

Comment: I edited my post to add the recent code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your intention (change value of bInA from C), your recent edit seems to work fine.  Here's my java version of your pseudocode.

```
class A 
{
    B bInA;
    C cInA;

    public void foo(int someValue)
    {
         cInA = new C();
         bInA = new B();
         cInA.foo(bInA, someValue);
         System.out.println(bInA.value);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         A myA = new A();
         myA.foo(123);
         // myA.bInA.value should be equal to xyz
    }
}

class B { int value; }

class C 
{
    public void foo(B bInA, int someValue)
    {
          bInA.value = someValue;
    }
}
```

Output

```
123
```

Comment: I am actually trying to implement an algorithm which needs to do something like what is happening in the pseudo code. And I think if this method works, I might be doing something wrong in some other place in my code. I will check and get back. Thank you.

Comment: I now found out where I was going wrong. Your response answers my question. Thank you. @TedBigham

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have pass-by-reference; rather, all you ever have are references to objects, and those references must be passed by value. So your code is roughly equivalent to something like this in C++:

```
class A {
  private:
    B *bInA = NULL;
    C *cInA = NULL;

  public:
    void foo(someValue) {
      cInA->foo(bInA, someValue);
    }

    static void main() {
      A *myA = new A();
      myA->foo(xyz)

      // myA->bInA->value should be equal to xyz
    }
}

int main() {
    A::main();
    return 0;
}

class B { ... }

class C {
  public:
    void foo(bInA, someValue) {
      bInA = new B(); // defeats the point of having passed in a bInA
      bInA->value = someValue;
    }
}
```

(Except that the C++ code has memory leaks, since you allocate some things without freeing them, whereas in Java that's not an issue.)

Comment: So does that mean I cannot achieve this in JAVA?

Comment: @HarshShah: I guess so. I mean, Java and C++ are both complete languages -- anything you might need to do, you can do in both -- but not all concepts map one-to-one, so if you express a problem in Java terms, then some parts of it might be unachievable in C++, and if you express it in C++ terms, then some parts of it might be unachievable in Java. That's why you have to express the problem in its own terms, and solve it in whatever language you're trying to solve it in.